# What is a Crescent Jetpack, and where can I get one?

Tags: global-agenda

I'm enjoying my newly minted copy of Global Agenda from the recent steam sale, but I can't help but notice that the documentation on the game is rather sparse -- a far cry from the encyclopedias of WoW-everything I've been spoiled to have had.

I see a lot of peple spamming the in-game trade chat for something called 'Crescent Jetpacks', and while the [Global Agenda Wiki](http://globalagenda.wikia.com/wiki/Jetpack) acknowledges that they *exist*, that's really all it has to say about them.

So two-part question: What is the difference between a Crescent Jetpack and a standard combat jetpack, and how can I get my hands on one (assuming I don't want to buy it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it's taken 3 weeks, I finally have some new concrete data.

The biggest difference between Crescent Jetpacks and the Combat Jetpacks is that while the latter can be bought at an in-game store for 'tokens' (one of the two currencies in the game), the former exists only as an epic drop from PvP missions. The drop rate is quite low, but HiRez has indicated that they will be increasing the drop rate next patch (1.4).

The primary *use* difference between the two is the reduced power cost. Normal Jetpacks cost 6.2 power baseline, while the prototype Crescent Jetpacks cost 5.9 power (which is, as mentioned on the Wiki, about 5% less). As my Medic is not yet level 40, I can't make estimates on the speed or turning ability of the crescent jetpack (which is noted to be increased).

The final difference is simply a cosmetic one: Crescent jetpacks look different than both the normal / hands-free jetpacks, as well as the combat jetpacks (which share the Crescent's ability to fire weapons while in use). In particular, each Crescent Jetpack has an upturned Crescent worked into the design.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The article on the Global Agenda wiki got updated and answering your questions: "Global Agenda features 3 types of Jetpacks - Regular, Hands-Free, and Combat. As of patch 1.39, which reached live servers on December 3rd, there is a fourth type, the Crescent Jetpack, which can be looted at the end of a successful mercenary PvP match. These are statistically identical to Combat Jetpacks, take about 5% less energy and fly a bit faster.

Comment: No... the wiki has still not been updated. This is no new information.

Comment: Well then i'm sorry but even for me as GA newbie (only played to Lv 35 or so) every information you asked for is included in the wiki article